# AngularJS element.innerHTML is undefined from within directive

Tags: angularjs, innerhtml, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have:

```
directives.directive('foo', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope: true,
        link:function (scope, element, attr) {

            console.log('innerHTML is ' + element.innerHTML);

            scope.$watch('update', function (newValue) {
                console.log('innerHTML is... ' + element.innerHTML);
            });

        }
    }
});
```

... then innerHTML is undefined.  I imagine this is due to the way Angular processes the DOM.  What is the right way to obtain the innerHTML?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `element` variable that is passed to your `link` function is a jqLite object - not a DOM object. You can obtain the DOM object with `element[0]` (like you could in jQuery), but jqLite provides a method for you: `element.html()`. Check out the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element).

Comment: Thank you.  Exactly what I was missing.