# Nested 'on' click and keypress functions not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  element.on("click", function(){
    element[0].querySelector("input").focus()
    element[0].querySelector("input").on('keypress',function(key){
        console.log(key)
    }
  })
```

This returns this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
runner:18(anonymous function) 
runner:18(anonymous function) 
angular.js:2843forEach 
angular.js:325eventHandler
```

And the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jejuc/1/)

Thanks!

Comment: it will register the event for the following keypress, no?

Comment: Usually if there's an error, it would be awesome for us to be able to see it ;)

Comment: There are syntax errors in your posted example. Have you checked the console log to make sure you have fixed any syntax errors?

Comment: Semi-colon key broken? :)

Comment: Semi-colons aren't required in JavaScript, they're good practice though. There is no syntax error here.

Comment: @SterlingArcher No, semi-colons are not required, but the missing `)` is definitely a syntax error

Comment: @SterlingArcher I wasn't referring to the semicolons... there is a missing close parenthesis after the curly bracket after the second `on`

Comment: Ahh sorry, missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) returns a DOM object. The `.on` function is a jQuery function. You need to wrap it:

```
$(element[0].querySelector("input")).on('keypress',function(key){
    console.log(key)
}
```

Also, I would be weary of adding event handlers inside of other event handlers. Whenever you click the element, the keypress event will be added. If you click the element 5 times, the input will now have 5 active keypress events unless you're removing it at some point. You should only do it if you're aware of these implications - and even then it can make code hard to follow.

Comment: "Also, I would be weary of adding event handlers inside of other event handlers." Why's that?

Comment: @Ninsly I would add that info to the answer.

Comment: Yes, add that to answer and perhaps a `.unbind('keypress')` ?

Comment: @jwatts1980 Thanks, I just added it and removed the comment.

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy That would work, but as per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/), using `.off('keypress')` is preferred

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy Are you aware that you can use `this` instead of `element[0]` inside the event function to refer to the clicked element? The `element[0]` seems like an odd implementation unless you have a specific reason for it.

Comment: Yeah, its angularjs providing the element as such

Comment: Explains why use `element[0]` => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800443/angularjs-element-innerhtml-is-undefined-from-within-directive